# Get the number of SPCurrent users in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I get the number of logged in users on a SharePoint site?

Is there an OTB way, or it should be done programmatically?

And how can I proceed? 
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can get this OOTB. You need to either get the 3rd party solution or developed your own solution.

Here is some useful resources.

[Find Number of Users Currently Logged on to a SharePoint Site](http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site)

[Get all the unique users in a farm using PowerShell script](http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/160/Get-all-the-unique-users-in-a-farm-using-PowerShell-script)

[Find Number of Users Currently Logged on to a SharePoint 2013 Online using SPServices](http://www.microsofttechnology.net/2013/10/find-number-of-users-currently-logged.html)

Comment: Find Number of Users Currently Logged on to a SharePoint 2013 Online using SPServices ,this is the perfect one